# How to upload file using graphql-client?

Tags: c#, graphql, graphql-dotnet

How can I make a mutation call from a client and upload a file?
I can do it in the editor (screen)[image]
But I cannot figure out how to make the same from a client

```
var request = new GraphQLRequest
            {
                Query = query,
                Variables = new { id = "id" },
            };

            var graphQLResponse = await _client.SendMutationAsync<dynamic>(request );
```

where should I put the byte[] from an image?

Comment: It's not about HotChocolate, it's about graphql-client. And as I can see graphql-client doesn't support file uploading: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client/issues/101